# Customer-Supplied Encryption Key feature is not available (but it is!)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Not had a problem using the Customer-Supplied Encryption Key feature until today, when trying to access some stored files this error keeps appearing, even though it is supported in the UK and has been working perfectly fine for the past 18 months until now.

Am using the service via the Firebase Spark Plan so cannot ask Google for help directly, so just wondering if anyone else is having an issue?

Comment: With this description I can understand that you are not able to use it because of the restrictions [1]. Did you change anything on your project? Can you grant that you are not falling in any of the restrictions? 

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys#restrictions

Comment: @TasosV No code has been changed/modified in anyway relating to this since it was first successfully working, and as far as I'm aware has been working up until this morning (but certainly was working on 18th, which I note was the date the docs were last updated but appear no different restriction-wise to previous version https://web.archive.org/web/20181223160100/https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys). With nothing changing, as far as I'm aware no restrictions have been broken :S

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the circumstances you described I advise you even if you don't have enough support level to open a ticket to our support platform, you can create a private issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491168) specifying your Google Cloud Project Number and the link to this Stackoverflow question. If you follow this process, I'll be able to get this case, because I'm sure that we will need to perform some actions on your project to investigate deeper the root cause.

Comment: many thanks for the response, I have just now opened a ticket in the issue tracker with a similar title and referenced this SO issue